# How do I load an external API before an Angular controller references it in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am loading the youtube api into my app. My angular controller references the api before the api has fully loaded which throws an error. How can I load the api fully before angular tries to call it?

application.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Movie Text Alert</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body ng-app="movieApp">

  <%= yield %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>


</body>
</html>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree .

$(document).foundation();

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCwxiOWzN5SQpc4_85EiSTpAZxJFfMe9uE');
    console.log("key loaded");
}
```

controller code

```
movieApp.controller('MovieController', [ '$http', '$scope', 'Movie', function($http, $scope, Movie) {

var apiURL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=d0a8b0361581f05b502a995a7cf2e923";
var poster_directory = "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w500";

$scope.movies = [ ];
var sorted_movie_array = [ ];

//call api and build sorted movie array to display on page
$http({ method: 'GET', url: apiURL })
    .success(function(data) {

        for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var movieObj = {
                title: '',
                poster: '',
                release_date: ''
            };

            //assign title
            movieObj.title = data.results[i].title;

            //assign poster image
            //no image available for the movie so we use a default image
            if (data.results[i].poster_path == null) {
                movieObj.poster = "/assets/no-image.png";
            }
            else {
                movieObj.poster = poster_directory + data.results[i].poster_path;
            }

            //assign release date
            movieObj.release_date = data.results[i].release_date;

            //call youtub api search function here
            search();

            sorted_movie_array.push(movieObj);
        }

         //sort by newest date
        sorted_movie_array.sort(function(a, b){
                var dateA = new Date(a.release_date);
                var dateB = new Date(b.release_date);
                return dateA - dateB;
        });

        $scope.movies = sorted_movie_array;

    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
```

youtube api code

```
function search() {
    console.log("inside search function");
    onClientLoad();
    var query = "john wick trailer";
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: query
    });
    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}

// Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
function showResponse(response) {
    var yData = response;
    var imageURL, title, link;

    for (var i = 0; i < yData.items.length; i++) {
        imageURL = yData.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
        title = yData.items[i].snippet.title;
        link = yData.items[i].id.videoId;
        console.log(link);
        //$('#images').append('<li><img src=' + imageURL + '><p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + link + '">' + title + '</a></p></li>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a factory to create a youtube service like so...

```
movieApp.factory('YoutubeSvc', ['$resource', '$q', function($resource, $q){....
```